# Error expected ';' before ''

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>                          
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     double a, b, c, x, y; 
     cout<<"x = ";
     cin>>x;
     if (fabs(1-pow(x,2))==(a+c)) y=sqrt((fabs(a*x-pow(cos(pow(b,3)),2)*x+5.1*c)));
     else if (fabs(1-pow(x,2))>a+c) y=exp(0.04+x)+log(fabs(pow(b,2)*cos(x)));
     else (fabs(1-pow(x,2))<a+c) y=pow(cos(pow(b,2)*pow(x,2)),2)+log(fabs(pow(b*x-pow(a,2))));
     cout<<y;
     return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку [Error] expected ';' before 'y' в 12 строке:

```
else ((fabs(1-pow(x,2))<a+c)) y=pow(cos(pow(b,2)*pow(x,2)),2)+log(fabs(pow(b*x-pow(a,2))));
```

Если после else убрать условие код выдает следующую ошибку указывая на `pow(a,2)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>                            
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     double a, b, c, x, y; 
     cout<<"x = ";
     cin>>x;
     if (fabs(1-pow(x,2))==(a+c)) y=sqrt((fabs(a*x-pow(cos(pow(b,3)),2)*x+5.1*c)));
     else if (fabs(1-pow(x,2))>a+c) y=exp(0.04+x)+log(fabs(pow(b,2)*cos(x)));
12-->    else y=pow(cos(pow(b,2)*pow(x,2)),2)+log(fabs(pow(b*x-pow(a,2))));
     cout<<y;
     return 0;
}

12  65  [Error] no matching function for call to 'pow(double)'
```

Исправный и работающий код выглядит так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>                          
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     double a, b, c, x, y; 
     cout<<"x = ";
     cin>>x;
     if (fabs(1-pow(x,2))==(a+c)) y=sqrt((fabs(a*x-pow(cos(pow(b,3)),2)*x+5.1*c)));
     else if (fabs(1-pow(x,2))>a+c) y=exp(0.04+x)+log(fabs(pow(b,2)*cos(x)));
     else y=pow(cos(pow(b,2)*pow(x,2)),2)+log(fabs(b*x-pow(a,2)));
     cout<<y;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `else` пишется без условия.

Comment: [Error] 'else' without a previous 'if' выдаёт следующую ошибку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Исправьте старую ошибку и покажите новый код.

Comment: Комменты портят форматирование. Под вопросом есть кнопка [edit].

Comment: готово! можете проверить в чем дело? спасибо!

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. `else if (условие)` - нормальная вещь. `else (условие)` - ненормальная, нужно просто `else`.0

Comment: всё написано прямо, что непонятного? *Нет подходящей функции с таким именем и аргументом*

Comment: просто студент который только учит с++, училка отказывается объяснять, вот и полностью не соображаю) простите за тупость) а знаете как это исправить?

Comment: *"училка отказывается объяснять"* Привыкайте, это норма. *"no matching function for call to 'pow(double)'
"* Компилятор вам говорит, что вы передали один аргумент в pow. А нужно сколько?

Comment: спасибо, проблема решена!

Comment: простите, а что значит -inf в решении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else /*(fabs(1-pow(x,2))<a+c)*/ y=...
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Но это же комментарий, нет?

Comment: @LyingDeg Да. Это тонкий намек, что эту часть надо удалить.

Comment: теперь проблемы с [Error] no matching function for call to 'pow(double)'

Comment: @LyingDeg Если Вы считаете, что это не ответ, можете на него не смотреть.

Comment: @LyingDeg "теперь проблемы ..." - Вы что, в детском саду? Посчитайте сколько параметров Вы передаете в `pow`.

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: @LyingDeg "Один ..." и все.

Comment: а, всё теперь понял!! спасибо большое!

Comment: @LyingDeg Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.